# The SharedPreferences doesn't save the checked box in my Android app

Tags: java, android, sharedpreferences

I have a check box in an AlertDialog that starts when the app starts. I added "SharedPreferences" to save if the check box is checked or not. If the check box checked, the AlertDialog never starts or shows when the app starts. But my problem is: When I check that box, the AlertDialog starts in every time when I launch the app.

**checkbox.xml (layout file):**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:orientation="vertical" android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <CheckBox
        android:id="@+id/checkboxDialog"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_margin="5dp"
        style="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium" />

</LinearLayout>
```

The **onCreate method** in the **MainActivity.java**:

```
@Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        View checkBoxView = View.inflate(this, R.layout.checkbox, null);
        final CheckBox checkBox = (CheckBox) checkBoxView.findViewById(R.id.checkboxDialog);
        checkBox.setOnCheckedChangeListener(new CompoundButton.OnCheckedChangeListener() {
            @Override
            public void onCheckedChanged(CompoundButton buttonView, boolean isChecked) {
                SharedPreferences prefs = getSharedPreferences("state", 0);

                if(prefs.getBoolean("x", false) == true)
                {
                    checkBox.setChecked(true);
                }
                else if(checkBox.isChecked() == true)
                {
                    SharedPreferences myPrefs = getSharedPreferences("state", 0);
                    SharedPreferences.Editor editor = myPrefs.edit();
                    editor.putBoolean("x", true);
                    editor.commit();
                }
            }
        });
        checkBox.setText("Test");
        final Context context = this;
        AlertDialog.Builder mainDialog = new AlertDialog.Builder(context);
        mainDialog.setTitle("Test");
        mainDialog.setMessage("Test my dialog!");
        mainDialog.setView(checkBoxView);
        mainDialog.setPositiveButton("Go to website", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
                Intent browseIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW, Uri.parse("https://www.google.com"));
                startActivity(browseIntent);
            }
        });
        AlertDialog alertDialog = mainDialog.create();
        alertDialog.show();

        ...
    }
```

Comment: you are never initialising your checkbox with the value from sharedpreferences..

Comment: @Tobrun Can you explain more?! because I never used the SharedPreferences before. Thanks.

Comment: add something like *checkBox.setChecked(myPrefs.getBoolean("x",false));* in onCreate

Comment: @Tobrun I added that line of code, but same problem!

Comment: Take a closer look at your `onCheckedChanged()` callback: once you check your checkbox and write its state, you'll never write it again because you'll always end up in the first if-branch. You don't need `SharedPreferences` out there anyway. Simple debugging would solve your problems.

Comment: @SqueezyMo I am a beginner, I never used the debugging before and I don't know how I use it! If you can help me with the correct code. Thanks.

Comment: But I told you what's wrong with your code. Just put `Log.d()` calls in relevant parts of your method and see how the execution flows. You'll notice the flaw before long.

Comment: @SqueezyMo Why use `Log`, which is for, er, logging, instead of the debugger?  The debugger will find it in 30 seconds.

Comment: @MrGlitch Trying to build apps without knowing how to use the debugger is like trying to build a house with no cement.  Just Google for it.

Comment: @Simon Because debugging is not limited to using debugger. See what `d()` stands for. Print statements is the simplest approach, surely not the only one.

Comment: @SqueezyMo Debugging with logging is about the hardest way to do it.  Reserved for those really difficult bugs related to threading, race conditions etc.  Bugs like this are much easier to fix with the debugger and the Android community does a lousy job of explaining how to debug to noobs.

Comment: @Simon Logging lets you see the whole picture at a glance. I usually find myself using logging more often than the debugger. Matter of preference, I guess, so there's no ground for arguing. In simple scenarios any approach will do.

Comment: @Simon I found a small bug in this line `if(prefs.getBoolean("x", false) == true)` by using the debugger (Changed to `prefs.getBoolean("x", false) == false`), but the main problem I didn't find a solution for it. :(

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**I found the answer here:**

- http://examples.javacodegeeks.com/android/core/content/android-sharedpreferences-example/

**Hope it will help others.**

**Thanks.**